# Which Sign Up button shall we use for our web app to get the most sign-ups?

Tags: website-design, buttons

**We want to improve our sign up button.** In this set of images below, which do you think should give more clicks for people to sign up?

To give everyone brief info of what MYCURE is... MYCURE is the Most Complete Clinic Management System in the Philippines. It is a web and mobile application that aims to make Clinic and Hospital operations faster and more efficient. Kindly visit https://mycure.md/ for more information.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

***My bet is on the second photo.*** Although the last photo is good enough to catch attention, I am worried about the imbalance in the aesthetics of the site.

Thanks.

Comment: I assume your question can be rephrased as "what SingUp prompt shall we use for our service to get the most sign-ups?" What does your service provide? Why a user would "get" MyCure instead of "joining" you? Or perhaps "trying" MyCure first would attract more customers? Share more of the context, please.

Comment: Okay will rephrase the Title. The text field labels title, so I put a title on it, instead of the actual question. My Bad. Thanks for noticing though. Will add more context on the website.

Comment: Why don't you A/B test with all these variants and then tell us the real answer? We don't know, we can only guess.

Comment: Try testing the variants with users specific to you demographic. If you can't find user in your demographic try places online like https://usabilityhub.com/

Comment: @SergeyKirienko Thanks. We want to trim down the choices before we do the A/B Test.

Comment: @AntonMircea Thanks this is interesting. Will use this. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 2):

I also agree on finding a way to A/B test, because our suggestions are coming from an assumption of what your target would do. You’d be surprised sometimes. If it’s an option for you to A/B test, I would try a warm color like orange (I see you using it to highlight some text) to add some good contrast between the button and your main color scheme. Some even go as far as using a dark red color and it makes a huge difference. You have to use your eye to ensure it’s not extreme and fits well with the theme. Please take as a suggestion for consideration. Also I would definitely test with “Sign Up”.

Comment: Absolutely...best of luck to you.